# Django Queryset to return objects in Many to Many fields

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a database table like this :

```
ID    epic_key     issue_key     status
1     JIR-1         JIR-12        TODO
2     JIR-2         JIR-13        OPEN
3     JIR-2         JIR-18        CLOSE
4     JIR-2         JIR-88        TODO
5     JIR-3         JIR-89        TODO
6     JIR-3         JIR-99        CLOSE
```

In a Django template (index.html), I want to display all `issue_key` related with unique `epic_key` values. All the information should be displayed in the table in one go.
For eg. For `JIR-2` `epic_ke`y, display all `issue_keys` It should be like `Select issue_key where epic_key is "epic_key"`

```
JIR-2  JIR-13
       JIR-18
       JIR-88

JIR-3  JIR-89
       JIR-99
```

A collapsible block, a table, accordion anything can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = issue_key.objects.filter(epic_key__in=epic_key_set)
```

[Making queries#in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in)

To use it in the template you need to pass it as part of the context:

```
context['issue_keys']=keys
return render(request, TEMPLATE_NAME, context)
```

And then in the template:

```
{% for key in issue_keys %}
    <p>Key: {{ key }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Where to put this piece of code and then use it in template.
I am new to Django

Comment: Should it be MODELNAME.object.filter(epic_key__in=epic_key_set) ??

Comment: Updated my answer. And yes, `issue_key` in `issue_key.objects.filter(epic_key__in=epic_key_set)` is MODELNAME.

Comment: One more question, What does "epic_key_set" refer to ?

Comment: I tried using this in epic_key_set = MYMODELNAME.objects.values('epic_key').distinct(). When I use the code you provided in template it just gives me all the issue_keys without segregating them according to epic_keys. Please correct me if I am wrong